# How to access android system settings with Unity in C#

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, settings, system

I'm making an app and need to be able to check if settings like : Bluetooth/Phone Rotation/Flashlight/Plane Mode/GPS/Phone Brightness/Silent Mode, are activated on an android phone.

I haven't found any way to do it within Unity, using C#. I found ways to do it using Xamarin but none of them work with Unity (or maybe I haven't done it right), the only way I found is using Java and making it into a plugin and call it in a C# script. But I can't find a clear way to make this work. If this is the only solution could you please explain how to do it, all the documentation I find is from old versions from 2014.

I think there is a simple solution for this but I simply can't find it. And the manifest part is not a problem, I'll add the permissions needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Java** the methods you want to call should be public or static,  you must build your java source as a library (in build.gradle: `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`), and add the .aar to Unity's `Assets/Plugins/Android/` folder.

Then you can instantiate your plugin in **Unity** like so:

```
    // this class string is the package at the top of your Java class extended with the class name, e.g.: 
    // package com.yourcompany.you.package;
    string classString = "com.yourcompany.you.package.className";
    // Get the class
    var tempAjc = new AndroidJavaClass(classString);
    // Here you can call a static method on the class that returns an instance of the class if you want to pass some parameters upon creation
    _androidObject = tempAjc.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("CreateInstance",
    new object[] {arg1, arg2});
    // non static call on your new instance
    _androidObject.Call("PassingMoreStuff", initParam);
    // if you want to return something from Java to Unity:
    int javaVal = _androidObject.Call<int>(methodName, parameters);
```

Comment: Excellent, feel free to mark this as the answer then.